# RegEx for 9 digit number in a particular format

Tags: regex

Just starting out with coding. I was able to grasp the basics, need help with this one in particular. I want to validate a field, to accept only 9 digit numbers in the following format:

> **A**BC**00**WXYZ

Where the **2 digits in the middle are always 0**, and the **first digit cannot be zero**. The *digits not in bold text* can be anything between 0-9

Comment: You should include your current attempts in the question.

Comment: you didnt even provide a 9 digit string

Comment: Try [regex101](https://regex101.com) for creating, testing and understanding regexes.

Comment: The votes to close this question are absurd. Welcome to programming nrml and don't let these people discourage you.

Comment: This is shorthand for it:  `[1-9]\d{2}00\d{4}`

Comment: @erisco : thanks, looks like not everyone is kind to the noob :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use following regex :

```
'[1-9][0-9]{2}00[0-9]{3}'
```

Read more about [character-class](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html) and [repetition](http://www.regular-expressions.info/repeat.html)